# How to write Unit Test for HTTPBuilder using SPOCK framework?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock, httpbuilder

I want the Unit Test to go through both, Success and Failure execution paths. How to make the test case to go to Success or Failure path?

```
void addRespondents()
{
      
            http.request(POST, TEXT) {
                uri.path = PATH
                headers.Cookie = novaAuthentication
                headers.Accept = 'application/json'
                headers.ContentType = 'application/json'
                body = respondentString
                response.success = { resp, json ->
                    statusCode = 2
                   
                }
                
                response.failure = { resp, json ->
                    if(resp.status == 400) {
                        statusCode = 3
                        def parsedJson = new JsonSlurper().parse(json)
                        
                    }else{
                        autoCreditResponse =  createErrorResponse(resp)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions, providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In addition to what @cfrick said, not even your class under test is complete. Where do for example `POST`, `TEXT`, `PATH`, `headers`, `body`, `response` come from? It seems like you do not like dependency injection, which would make mock-testing easier. Instead, you use lots of "global" variables (from the perspective of the method under test), i.e. the easiest way to cover all execution paths is to change those before running the test.

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback. You asked a question, I spent considerable effort answering it and there was no reaction from you whatsoever. Please at least be polite enough to either accept the answer (click on the grey checkmark, making it green) or leave a comment if you think something is wrong with the answer. This is how it works here on SO. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems you use this library:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Because I never used HTTPBuilder before and it looks like a nice tool when using Groovy, I played around with it a bit, replicating your use case, but converting it into a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have to admit that testability for this library is in bad shape. Even the tests for the library itself are no proper unit tests, but rather integration tests, actually performing network requests instead of mocking them. The tool itself also contains to test mocks or hints about how to test.

Because the functionality heavily relies on dynamically binding variables in closures, mock-testing is somewhat ugly and I had to look into the tool's source code in order to pull it off. Nice black-box testing is basically impossible, but here is how you can inject a mock HTTP client returning a predefined mock response which contains enough information not to derail the application code:

#### Class under test

As you can see, I added enough data in the class to be able to run it and do something meaningful. The fact that your method returns `void` instead of a testable result and we only have to rely on testing side effects, does not make testing easier.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68093910

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST

class JsonApiClient {
  HTTPBuilder http = new HTTPBuilder("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
  String PATH = "/users"
  String novaAuthentication = ''
  String respondentString = ''
  String autoCreditResponse = ''
  int statusCode
  JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

  void addRespondents() {
    http.request(POST, TEXT) {
      uri.path = PATH
      headers.Cookie = novaAuthentication
      headers.Accept = 'application/json'
      headers.ContentType = 'application/json'
      body = respondentString
      response.success = { resp, json ->
        println "Success -> ${jsonSlurper.parse(json)}"
        statusCode = 2
      }

      response.failure = { resp, json ->
        if (resp.status == 400) {
          println "Error 400 -> ${jsonSlurper.parse(json)}"
          statusCode = 3
        }
        else {
          println "Other error -> ${jsonSlurper.parse(json)}"
          autoCreditResponse = createErrorResponse(resp)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  String createErrorResponse(HttpResponseDecorator responseDecorator) {
    "ERROR"
  }
}
```

#### Spock specification

This spec covers all 3 cases for responses in the above code, using an unrolled test which returns different status codes.

Because the method under test returns `void`, I decided to verify the side effect that `HTTPBuilder.request` was actually called. In order to do this, I had to use a `Spy` on the `HTTPBuilder`. Testing for this side effect is optional, then you do not need the spy.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68093910

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static org.apache.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1

class JsonApiClientTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll
  def "verify status code #statusCode"() {

    given: "a JSON response"
    HttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(
      new BasicStatusLine(HTTP_1_1, statusCode, "my reason")
    )
    def json = "{ \"name\" : \"JSON-$statusCode\" }"
    response.setEntity(new StringEntity(json))
    
    and: "a mock HTTP client returning the JSON response"
    HttpClient httpClient = Mock() {
      execute(_, _ as ResponseHandler, _) >> { List args ->
        (args[1] as ResponseHandler).handleResponse(response)
      }
    }

    and: "an HTTP builder spy using the mock HTTP client"
    HTTPBuilder httpBuilder = Spy(constructorArgs: ["https://foo.bar"])
    httpBuilder.setClient(httpClient)
    
    and: "a JSON API client using the HTTP builder spy"
    def builderUser = new JsonApiClient(http: httpBuilder)

    when: "calling 'addRespondents'"
    builderUser.addRespondents()

    then: "'HTTPBuilder.request' was called as expected"
    1 * httpBuilder.request(POST, TEXT, _)

    where:
    statusCode << [200, 400, 404]
  }
}
```

If you have used Spock for a while, probably I do not need to explain much. If you are a Spock or mock testing beginner, probably this is a bit too complex. But FWIW, I hope that if you study the code, you can wrap your head around how I did it. I tried to use Spock label comments in order to explain it.

#### Console log

The console log indicates that all 3 execution paths are covered by the specification:

```
Success -> [name:JSON-200]
Error 400 -> [name:JSON-400]
Other error -> [name:JSON-404]
```

If you use a code coverage tool, of course you do not need the log statements I inserted into the application code. They are just for demonstration purposes.

---

#### Verifying the result of `http.request(POST, TEXT) {...}`

In order to circumvent the fact that your method returns `void`, you can save the result of `HTTPBuilder.request(..)` by stubbing the method call in the spy interaction, passing through the original result at first, but also checking for the expected result.

Simply add `def actualResult` somewhere in the `given ... and` blocks (in `when` it is too late), then assign the result of `callRealMethod()` to it and then compare to `expectedResult` like this:

```java
    and: "a JSON API client using the HTTP builder spy"
    def builderUser = new JsonApiClient(http: httpBuilder)
    def actualResult

    when: "calling 'addRespondents'"
    builderUser.addRespondents()

    then: "'HTTPBuilder.request' was called as expected"
    1 * httpBuilder.request(POST, TEXT, _) >> {
      actualResult = callRealMethod()
    }
    actualResult == expectedResult

    where:
    statusCode << [200, 400, 404]
    expectedResult << [2, 3, "ERROR"]
```

If you prefer a data table instead of data pipes, the `where` block looks like this:

```java
    where:
    statusCode | expectedResult
    200        | 2
    400        | 3
    404        | "ERROR"
```

I think this pretty much covers all that makes sense to test here.

Comment: Great and extensive answer! Now that you've shown that it is possible, I would ask if we should. And I normally recommend not mocking http clients, there is so much going on inside, that this can lead to a sense of false security. Instead, encapsulating the client related code into a dedicated interface/class that can be mocked to test the business logic, and using mockserver integration test to validate the client code.

Comment: I beg to differ: (1) A real unit test should mock server connections. That in this case it is tricky means that the tool should be refactored to provide better testability, not to avoid mocking the HTTP client. (2) Replacing a mock client by a mock server does not solve the problem that you are not testing the real thing. (3) Using a server mock for a semi-integrative test is a great idea, but IMO should neither replace a properly isolated (super-fast) unit test nor a real integration test. Doing one thing does not mean not doing the other one. We need both!